# Calculate size of NSAttributedString from HTML

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I am using a UITextView to display an NSAttributedString from some given HTML, which can includes elements such as bold, italicized, lists, marked, super & subscript, etc.

Currently the code below works pretty well for just paragraphs of text, but once I start adding more complicated elements such as lists and line breaks, the sizing is completely off.

```
// Create the NSMutableAttributedString from given HTML
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:options
                               documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

// Max size for the text container (no limit on height)
CGSize bounds = CGSizeMake(320.0, CGFLOAT_MAX);

// Set the font and size for better rendering results
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto" size:14.0];
NSDictionary *attrFont = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, str.length);
[str addAttributes:attrFont range:range];

// Calcualte the size of the UITextView based on the above parameters
CGRect rect = [str boundingRectWithSize:bounds options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|        NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics context:nil];
```

I've done some searching and found this thread, but after trying what is suggested over there it still doesn't appear to be working, wondering if anyone knows of a better way to do this?

[Calculate Height Of NSAttributedString Containing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322345/calculate-height-of-nsattributedstring-containing-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after much fiddling around I found that the sizes are actually correct, but the `UITextView` has some padding / insets that cause the overflow. Setting the following on the textView fixed the problem

```
[self.textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Comment: There's a big difference between *"the sizing is completely off"* and it being off just a little due to the small text view insets. BTW - the other solution is to adjust the calculated size of the text by the text view's insets.

Comment: @rmaddy at first glance it was completely off (lopping off entire lines), but ya I can update the wording.

Comment: @rmaddy how would you calculate with the insets?

Comment: Add the text view's insets to the calculated `rect`.